# Rename product page with web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, asp-classic, web-config

Since I have this URL:

```
http://namedomain.com/product.asp?id=01&color=05&name=xxxx
```

What is the better approach to rewrite this URL like this:

```
http://namedomain.com/xxxx
```

With IIS I was able to generate this URL

```
http://namedomain.com/01/05/xxxx
```

This is the web.config code:

```
<rule name="RedirecionaPagProduto" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^exibe_produtos\.asp$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^produto=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;cor=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;url=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RenamePagProduto" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="exibe_produtos.asp?produto={R:1}&amp;cor={R:2}&amp;url={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Will your page work with just the "name" Querystring value or does it need "id" and "color"?

Comment: @John needs the ID and Color, but I want to show only the "name"...

Comment: If it needs the id and colour the page has to read those values from somewhere and it looks like it needs to get them from the url.  If you're able to get round that, maybe by posting them as form variables or storing them in the session object then you can leave them out of the URL